# AS3 - Capitalize every word in a sentence

Tags: actionscript-3

How to capitalize the first letter of every word in a sentence? (Similar to CSS *text-transform capitalize*)

Thank you.
Uli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression replace:

```
var str:String = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
str = str.replace(/(^[a-z]|\s[a-z])/g, function():String{ return arguments[1].toUpperCase(); });
```

Comment: How to turn it into a function? I tried the following which didn't work: `function capitalizeText(str:String) {
str.replace(/(^[a-z]|\s[a-z])/g)
return arguments[1].toUpperCase()
}
`

Comment: That would be something like:
`function capitalize(str:String):String {
return str.replace(/(^[a-z]|\s[a-z])/g, function():String { return arguments[1].toUpperCase(); } );
    }`
`trace(this.capitalize("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."));`

You need the inner function to actually capitalize the matches from the regular expression (which in this case are the all letter with a space or string start in front of it)
So if you need a function to capitalize the first letters you need two functions in total.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
function ucfirst(str:String):String {
   var words:Array = str.split(" ");
   for(var i in words) {
       words[i] = String(words[i]).charAt(0).toUpperCase() + String(words[i]).substr(1, String(words[i]).length);
   }
   return words.join(" ");
}
```